# Is passing on knowledge/information from one body to another and the resultant state is ever studied as any branch of physics?

Tags: education

Does any branch of physics, study the passing off of information/knowledge from one body to another ( body would obviously be living beings here, as they only can do so ). And resultant changes in the physical state of the universe because of that information.

For example, whatever physical state, a living being or nature exists, largely depends upon, how information has flowed to that particular point of time. Based on that information only, humans and other living beings act and behave. They react accordingly, resulting into chain of other events that ultimately decide state of non-living things in the nature.

A small example can be like two states of universe possible, when :

1) A person A tells ( informs ) B, there is a path-hole ahead.  ( Thus B is careful, and does not fall)

2) A person A does not tell B , about the path hole. ( B falls into the path-hole).

Comment: This seems a bit more like biology or cognitive science than physics. As far as I can tell, it's difficult to mathematically formalize concepts like human memory in a way that lends itself to symbolic manipulations or rigorous theorems that have useful predictive value.

Comment: You may be interested, speaking of Physics, in the concept of entropy, Shannon information theory, quantum information, Kolmogorov complexity. Look them up on Wikipedia, you may like them. However, as already noted, seems like your question (and, most of all, your example) could be better answered in a Biology forum.